# NSTextField with autosizing text looks terrible when in an NSCollectionView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, fonts, drawing, visual-glitch

I am having a little problem here. I have an NSCollectionView with a collection of views which have an NSTextField that shows fontnames in those fonts. Here is a screenshot:
[image: screenie]

As you can see, some fonts look glitched, they have their Interface Builder font-size behind them. I use this code to set the font size in `initWithFrame:` of the NSTextField:

```
  float targetWidth = rect.size.width - 10;
  float targetHeight = rect.size.height - 10;

  int i;
  for (i = 10; i < 100; i++) {
    NSDictionary *attrs = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSFont fontWithName:[self.font fontName] size:i], NSFontAttributeName, nil];
    NSSize strSize = [[self stringValue] sizeWithAttributes:attrs];
    [attrs release];
    if (strSize.width > targetWidth || strSize.height > targetHeight) {
      break;
    }
  }

  [self setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:[self.font fontName] size:(i - 1)]];
```

How can I fix this? It's looking terrible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This almost seems like it's more a problem with how the collection view is animated. Have you turned on wantsLayers for your prototype collection item view? Try turning it off. Also try putting an opaque view behind the text field so there's no transparency behind it all the way through to the collection view itself and see that improves things.

If that doesn't work, please clarify why and exactly how you're using the -initWithFrame: method of the text field ... seems to be a strange way of doing things.